# Where to get token and tenant ID?

Tags: personalization

I am having the requirement of using Sitecore AI -Auto Personalization on our site.
So with the help of installation guide, I installed `Sitecore AI Automated Personalization Standard 2.0.0` in sitecore 10 (on-Prem) in my local. In the guide they specify the `token`, `tenant ID` in the prerequisites.

Can anyone help me where to get the token, tenant ID or do I need to add the tenant ID and token?

[image]
I need to give values in the below areas.

[image]

I tried to set up Automation Personalization dashboard in Experience Optimization tool. but it showing an error like below.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the documentation, you will receive the token from your Sitecore representative. This does not come in the same package as the software and documentation that you received.

If you don't usually deal with your Sitecore representative directly, you might have to contact your internal leadership who handle relationships with Sitecore so that they can follow up and get you the details you need.

Comment: Hi Jason , Thankyou for your response. I reached out to the sitecore representative for the Token, Tenant Id .they asked me about  customer name of the environment that I am working with. I am trying to use the Sitecore AI Personalization in sitecore 10  which is running on my local machine .How can I find out the environment name . Do you have any idea about it.

Comment: Hi Nithya, SSE works best if different questions are asked separately for SEO, rather than using it as a conversation thread. You might want to either ask this as a new question, or jump over to Slack to have a chat.